# Table Inheritence is Slow with large table?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL. I have a statistics table with some columns. I intend to use single table inheritance e.g. have `InternetStatistics` inherit statistics. Will this cause query to be slow for large tables? Eventually, we are querying two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, table inheritance takes more resources when query as it is doing a join between two tables. So, avoid this when dealing with large tables.

Comment: To expand on this.. Data normalization is usually preferred to ensure data integrity and lower table sizes. de-normalization is preferred for performance, since a second operation is not needed to retrieve extra information. With proper indexing, negative performance impact will be minimized when using normalization techniques.